# C++ TreeNode parent Pointer?

Tags: binary-tree, treenode, data-representation

The Java `TreeNode` class contains references to both children and parent. I see sometimes in C++ implementations, there are only left, right children pointers and no parent pointer.

In a C++ implementation, should there be a parent pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a matter of what you want to do with your tree. In many cases (think expression trees) you only really need to know about your children. If this is the case, then having a pointer to the parent is irrelevant. So look at what you need to do. If your child node needs to know information about the parent, then a parent pointer will be necessary, but in most cases it really isn't.

If you can give a few more details about what you're doing, I can probably give a better answer about if your problem would be improved by having a parent pointer.

Comment: fair enough...it was a generic question to start with. I noticed that different references gave different implementation thus my question.

Comment: Perfectly valid question :) I have noticed C++ trees often ignore parent pointers. I know that I rarely use them.